# Selecting only one column from an excel file

Tags: r

```
uservec <- read_excel("~/ShinyUsers/File.xlsx", sheet = "Sheetname")
```

How do I select only the first column from the above? Is there a way of incorporating this into the read_excel code?

I've seen answers to similar questions saying that you need a range but I only want one column.

Comment: `... %>% select(FirstColumn)`?  or `read_excel(..., range="A:A")`?

Comment: it might help to read `?read_excel`.... there you will find handy stuff like `#read_excel(datasets, range = cell_cols("B:D"))`. Or does this not cover your usecase?